# How to convert cloudinary file in base64 string format in mvc c#

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller, base64, cloudinary

I want to get cloudinary file from cloudinary location in base64 string format.
Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try, where is the problem that you need help with? [ask] is a good read for beginners to write better, more successful questions.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to upload base64 image with C# and get the URL of the png image in response.

```
string cloud_name = "<Cloud Name>";
        string ApiKey = "<API KEY>";
        string ApiSecret = "<API SECRET>";

        Account account = new Account(cloud_name,ApiKey,ApiSecret);
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
        cloudinary.Api.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

         var ImguploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(@"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
         };


            var ImguploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(ImguploadParams);
            Console.WriteLine(ImguploadResult.SecureUri);

    }
```